# How to display multiple objects in a Cinnamon Applet

Tags: javascript, linux, applet, gnome, cinnamon

I am trying to write a Cinnamon Applet for my panels. I have figured out how to create a simple icon but I cannot figure out how can I get a second one to appear.

Here is my current simple code:

```
const Applet = imports.ui.applet;

class wholeModule extends Applet.Applet {
    constructor(orientation, panel_height, instance_id) {
        let icon = new someIcon(orientation, panel_height, instance_id);
        icon.updateIconName('google-chrome-symbolic');

        let icon2 = new someIcon(orientation, panel_height, instance_id);
        icon2.updateIconName('google-chrome');

        return icon;
    }
}

class someIcon extends Applet.IconApplet {
    constructor(orientation, panel_height, instance_id) {
        super(orientation, panel_height, instance_id);

        this.set_applet_icon_name('user-desktop-symbolic');
        this.set_applet_tooltip(_('test text'));
    }

    updateIconName(name) {
        this.set_applet_icon_name(name);
    }

    setToolTip(text) {
        this.set_applet_tooltip(_(text));
    }
}

function main(metadata, orientation, panel_height, instance_id) {
    return new wholeModule(orientation, panel_height, instance_id);
}
```

I am trying to create a workspace-switcher that has icons instead of text labels on my side panel and this part is what I cannot wrap my brain around.

I get that the main function calls for an object that ends up displayed on the Applet. How can I spawn another icon from someIcon class?

Comment: Hi Artem! Have you made it? Is it free license and if yes, where can I see the code? I want to have nice workspace indicator, now I want to change font/backgound of https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/222 (Workspace Name). TIA

Comment: Hi @AlexMartian - sorry but I switched away from cinnamon and haven't touched this since posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General approach

The class `IconApplet` is only able to handle one icon. I would use the code of that class as a template to write a class `MultiIconApplet` that is able to handle multiples.

You can find the original code in `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/applet.js` and search for `class IconApplet`. Copy it out and modify. Where one icon container is built, you can have an array of them:

```
var MultiIconApplet = class MultiIconApplet extends Applet {

    // provide the number of icons you need as an extra parameter
    _init(orientation, panel_height, icon_count, instance_id) {
        super._init(orientation, panel_height, instance_id);

        this.orientation = orientation; //orientation makes a difference
        this._applet_icon_boxes = [];   //array of containers
        this._applet_icons = [];        //array of icons

        for (var i = 0; i < icon_count; i++) {
             var box = new St.Bin();
             this._applet_icon_boxes.push(box);

             box.set_fill(true,true);
             box.set_alignment(St.Align.MIDDLE,St.Align.MIDDLE);
             this.actor.add(box);
    }

    // this method constructs the actual icons
    _ensureIcon(index) {
        if (!this._applet_icons[index] ||
            !(this._applet_icons[index] instanceof St.Icon))
            this._applet_icons[index] = new St.Icon({
                 reactive: true, track_hover: true,
                 style_class: 'applet-icon'
            });

        this._applet_icon_boxes[index].set_child(this._applet_icons[index]);
    }
```

Then, implement each of the `IconApplet` methods, but state the index of the icon you want to target. For example:

```
    set_applet_icon_name (index, icon_name) {
        this._ensureIcon(index);

        this._applet_icon[index].set_icon_name(icon_name);
        this._applet_icon[index].set_icon_type(St.IconType.FULLCOLOR);
        this._setStyle();
    }
```

Repeat for each of the methods, exchanging `this._applet_icon` with `this._applet_icons[index]`.

There is one method that overwrites the parent class method, so you need to implement that without parameter and loop through the icons:

```
    on_panel_height_changed_internal() {
        this.applet_icons.forEach((icon, index) => {
            if (icon) this._setStyle(index);
        )};
        this.on_panel_height_changed();
    }
```

Finally, you need to implement a reaction to orientation change, which is only an abstract method in the parent class:

```
    on_orientation_changed(neworientation) {
        this.orientation = neworientation;

        if (this.orientation == St.Side.TOP || this.orientation == St.Side.BOTTOM)
            this.actor.set_vertical(false);
        else
            this.actor.set_vertical(true);
    }
}
```

#### Specialized solution for a workspace switcher

Since what you want to achieve is a workspace switcher, you can also start out with the standard applet at `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/workspace-switcher@cinnamon.org` and modify its code.

All you need to do is look for the class `SimpleButton` in that applet, and where it adds a `St.Label` to represent the workspace, instead add a `St.Icon`:

```
class SimpleButton extends WorkspaceButton {
    constructor(index, applet) {
        super(index, applet);

        this.actor = new St.Button({ name: 'workspaceButton',
                                     style_class: 'workspace-button',
                                     reactive: applet._draggable.inhibit });

        if (applet.orientation == St.Side.TOP || applet.orientation == St.Side.BOTTOM) {
            this.actor.set_height(applet._panelHeight);
        } else {
            this.actor.set_width(applet._panelHeight);
            this.actor.add_style_class_name('vertical');
        }

        let icon = new St.Icon({
             icon_name: ..., // choose one based on index
             icon_size: applet.getPanelIconSize()
             style_class: 'applet-icon'
        });
        this.actor.set_child(icon);
        this.update();
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please help me with which I hope is even simpler related quesiton. TIA! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77216166/how-to-change-background-color-of-font-for-cinnamon-textapplet